# Getting a ubuntu installation disk

Tags: 12.04, downloads, lts, cd, sharing

Ok I'll make it simple. I live in Sri Lanka. And I dont have a good internet connection. So I already have ubuntu 10.10 which I got from shipit.ubuntu.com some time back. And distributed some copies of it to my friends so they have started to use linux like me. But the problem is I can't download the latest version of ubuntu LTS edition because of the weak internet connection I have. And also it's not available in shops in Sri Lanka(They also have the old version ordered from shipit) So is there anyway I can get a Ubuntu LTS CD shipped to my place so I can distribute copies of it to my friends. I really want one to give to people I know. So is there anyway I can get a Ubuntu disk shipped to my address?

Comment: welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I'm sorry but this does not really qualify the mandate of questions we look into here. However, please do drop a mail by to Canonical, their support team is the one you actually want to speak to. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your 10.10 CD is a coaster now. Don't try to install from it. I mean it. Frame it or throw it into the sea and don't look back. Cool people don't look back.

Firstly, try a torrent. Even on a weak internet connection you can usually get something downloaded and verified. This is because a torrent is chunked up into tiny bits and each bit needs to be verified before it's happy.

Then, if you're still desperate, get ready to pay for a CD. There are dozens of companies selling CD and USB versions of Linux. These are all under open licenses so you can copy them in most cases. Which one for you? Who knows. Google `buy linux cd` and see what looks good.

If you've got more patience, talk to your [Sri Lankan Team Loco](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SriLankanTeam). They're there to help Sri Lankan Ubuntu users out. I'd be shocked if somebody there couldn't send you a CD for the price of the media and postage (or less).

Failing that, you're in the position where you need to beg people. Or train pigeons to steal other people's CDs and fly them back to you... But I think the other options are fundamentally better.